# How do I format email composer in code

Tags: swift, email, ios9, mfmailcomposer

I am working on an app that has an email form which holds all the usual contact information.

I need to be able to format the email body with that information. I have done it successfully in the Android sister app, but I can't find how to achieve it in Swift.

> String message =
>                                                   "Name: " + txtFullName.getText().toString() + "\n" +
>                                                           "Street: " + txtStreet.getText().toString() + "\n" +
>                                                           "Suburb: " + txtSuburb.getText().toString() + "\n" +
>                                                           "State: " + spState.getSelectedItem().toString() + ", Post Code: " +
>   txtPostCode.getText().toString() + "\n" +
>                                                           "Phone number : " + txtPhone.getText().toString() + "\n\n" +
>
> "Have you ever tried before? " +
>   sp_ever_tried.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n\n" +
>                                                           "Would you be intereseted in Hosting a Facebook Party? " +
>   sp_hos_fb_party.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n\n" +
>                                                           "Would you like to become a Consultant? " +
>   sp_consultant_joiner.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n\n" +
>                                                           "Comments: \n" + txtComments.getText().toString();

Apologies about the code formatting in here.

in Swift I have :

```
@IBOutlet var txtFullName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtAddress: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtSuburb: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtPostCode: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtPhoneNumber: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtEmailAddresss: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtComments: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var txtTriedB4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtState: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtHostFBParty: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var txtJoinAsCons: UITextField!
```

Then in

```
@IBAction sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

       ...
      let msgBody = "<h3>Free Sample Request</H3>\n"
        "<b>Full Name: " + txtFullName.text! + "</b>\n"
        ...
    }
```

But I'm stuck here building the message body.

Comment: Oh.and yes I get that in the android code it is not HTML as in the Swift code and in the swift code I should be using <br> for new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
let msgBody = "Free Sample Request\n" "Full Name: \(txtFullName.text!)\n" + ...
```

I'd also recommend unwrapping your optionals before creating the message body using `if let` or `guard let` to avoid crashing if any of the fields are nil.

Comment: Thanks D. Greg, I will give it a shot and let you know how I go.

Comment: Worked a treat Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Be sure to select the answer as the correct one. ;)